# Client for many similar kinds of REST requests

Tags: c#, rest, client

I have a class that makes calls to a Web API (Using RestSharp), which  works fine but the code is super ugly. What would be the best way to refactor it? I thought of just doing a Facade pattern so all the calls that goes to cart will be in a separate class and order will be in an `order` class and so on.

All the methods looks very similar maybe I can extract something.

```
 public class ApiRestClient : IApiRestClient
    {

        private readonly RestClient _client;
        private readonly string _url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webapibaseurl"];

        public ApiRestClient()
        {
            _client = new RestClient(_url);
        }

        public TokenDto Get(Guid id)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("/cart/{id}", Method.GET) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
            request.AddParameter("id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

            var response = _client.Execute(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenDto>(response.Content);
        }

        public void SaveOrder(OrderDto order)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("/order/", Method.POST) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
            request.AddObject(order);
            _client.Execute<TokenDto>(request);
        }

        public string GetLayout(int? id)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("/customer/{id}", Method.GET) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
            request.AddParameter("id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            var response = _client.Execute(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDto>(response.Content).Layout;
        }

        public void UpdateUser(UserDto userMap)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("/user/", Method.POST) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
            request.AddObject(userMap);
            _client.Execute<UserDto>(request);
        }

        public IEnumerable<TokenDto> GetInvoices(Guid id)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("/receipt/{id}", Method.GET) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
            request.AddParameter("id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

            var response = _client.Execute(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<TokenDto>>(response.Content);
        }

        public TokenDto GetInvoice(Guid id)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("/receipt/invoice/{id}", Method.GET) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
            request.AddParameter("id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

            var response = _client.Execute(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenDto>(response.Content);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason for having a `readonly _url` in this class. In addition I don't see a reason to have a class level `_url` variable neither.
I would like to suggest having two constructors, one having a `string url` argument and one being argumentless. In this way it is easy without changing the `AppSettings` to have some flexibility.

Applying this would look like so

```
private readonly RestClient _client;

public ApiRestClient()
    : this(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webapibaseurl"])
{ }

public ApiRestClient(string url)
{
    _client = new RestClient(url);
}
```

It is not obvious from its name what the method `public TokenDto Get(Guid id)` will **get**. It seems from the resource that this would be a `cart`. Having a methodname, which makes it clear what the method is about, would be much better.

The `GetLayout()` method should be splitted into a `GetCustomer()` method (which you may need anyway) to only take the `Layout` of that returned `CustomerDto`.

The default `Method` for `RestRequest` is `Method.Get` so you could use the constructor which only takes `string resource` as a parameter.

The creation of this requests could be extracted to a method which takes a `string` and an `object` as parameter. Something along this lines

```
private RestRequest GetGetRequest(string resource, object value, string name)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(resource) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};

    request.AddParameter(name, value, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

    return request;
}
```

if you by any chance are using C# 6 you could use the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator like so

```
private RestRequest GetGetRequest(string resource, object id)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(resource) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};

    request.AddParameter(nameof(id), id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

    return request;
}
```

In the same way you could implement a `GetPostRequest()` method like so

```
private RestRequest GetPostRequest(string resource, object value)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

    request.AddObject(value);

    return request;
}
```

You could also add a generic method `ProcessRequest<T>` like so

```
private T ProcessRequest<T>(RestRequest request)
{
    var response = _client.Execute(request);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
}
```

(I don't really know if I like this).

Applying the mentioned points will lead to

```
public class ApiRestClient : IApiRestClient
{

    private readonly RestClient _client;

    public ApiRestClient()
        : this(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webapibaseurl"])
    { }

    public ApiRestClient(string url)
    {
        _client = new RestClient(url);
    }

    private RestRequest GetGetRequest(string resource, object value, string name)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(resource) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

        request.AddParameter(name, value, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        return request;
    }

    private T ProcessRequest<T>(RestRequest request)
    {
        var response = _client.Execute(request);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
    }

    public TokenDto GetCart(Guid id)
    {
        var request = GetGetRequest("/cart/{id}", id, "id");

        return ProcessRequest<TokenDto>(request);
    }

    public string GetLayout(int? id)
    {
        var customer = GetCustomer(id);

        return customer.Layout;
    }

    public CustomerDto GetCustomer(int? id)
    {
        var request = GetGetRequest("/customer/{id}", id, "id");

        return ProcessRequest<CustomerDto>(request);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TokenDto> GetInvoices(Guid id)
    {
        var request = GetGetRequest("/receipt/{id}", id, "id");

        return ProcessRequest<IEnumerable<TokenDto>>(request);
    }

    public TokenDto GetInvoice(Guid id)
    {
        var request = GetGetRequest("/receipt/invoice/{id}", id, "id");

        return ProcessRequest<TokenDto>(request);
    }

    private RestRequest GetPostRequest(string resource, object value)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

        request.AddObject(value);

        return request;
    }

    public void SaveOrder(OrderDto order)
    {
        var request = GetPostRequest("/order/", order);

        _client.Execute<TokenDto>(request);
    }

    public void UpdateUser(UserDto userMap)
    {
        var request = GetPostRequest("/user/", userMap);

        _client.Execute<UserDto>(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented the above and work really well, and as you mentioned it is way more flexible